# Android 7 buttons are not showing in XML

Tags: android, xml

I have a App with Login Layout So I have added 2 Buttons Save,Cancel

this is my XML Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#303F9F"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="My App Login"
            android:id="@+id/ota"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:gravity="bottom|left|center"
                android:id="@+id/tt5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/ui"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et3"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/et4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter User Name"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tt5"
                android:inputType="text"/>

            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:gravity="bottom|left|center"
                android:id="@+id/tt6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="@string/pw"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et4"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/et5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter Password"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tt6"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.0dip"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="@drawable/c_selector_btn"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here its working fine for android 5,6 but in android 7 buttons are not showing in emulator,xml,Real Device

But its not working in android 7

its showing like this

[image]

can any one suggest me what I am missing for android 7 in android XML.. I am using same in android 5,6 its worked but its not showing in 7

Comment: why don't you use linearlayout..?

Comment: if you use linearlayout & scrollview it will be solved..

Comment: No...I have some more options in that Relative layout is required..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="match_parenr"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:text="@string/save"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="@color/text_white"/>
```

You should give height of button to wrap_content

Comment: Thanks Its working.. I dont know How I made that mistake...haha

Answer (score 1):

You can try bellow like..

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <!--Header Hear-->

   <!-- Content Here -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight=".1"
      android:background="#FFFFFF"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_message_reset_new_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

      <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:gravity="bottom|left|center"
                android:id="@+id/tt5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="User Id"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et3"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/et4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter User Name"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tt5"
                android:inputType="text"/>

             <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:gravity="bottom|left|center"
                android:id="@+id/tt6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="password"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/et4"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <EditText android:id="@+id/et5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Enter Password"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tt6"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:text="save"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="#97d1ea"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="cancel"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                android:background="#97d1ea"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

            </LinearLayout>
          </ScrollView>
       </LinearLayout>


       <!--Footer Hear-->
   </LinearLayout>
```